# Remove XML items with regex

Tags: xml, notepad++

I'm trying to remove results form an xml file where the `<year>` is 2014. There are multiple years and I want to remove the whole `<stageassessment>` if it is from `2014`.

Using Notepad++, I've tried using regex but can't get my head around the correct format.

Hope that make sense.

```
<StageAssessment>
<Locale>ENG</Locale>
<Year>2014</Year>
<Subject>SCI</Subject>
<Method>TA</Method>
<Component>AT1</Component>
<ResultStatus>R</ResultStatus>
<ResultQualifier>NL</ResultQualifier>
<Result>3</Result>
<ResultDate>2014-07-25</ResultDate>
</StageAssessment>
```

Comment: It is very easy to write such a regex, but not easy to understand. Here it is: `(?s)<StageAssessment>(?:(?!</?StageAssessment>).)*<Year>2014</Year>(?:(?!</?StageAssessment>).)*</StageAssessment>`. And this one is much better: `<StageAssessment>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?StageAssessment>|Year>)[^<]*)*<Year>2014</Year>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?StageAssessment>)[^<]*)*</StageAssessment>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try regular expressions for this task, but the best way to manipulate XML is via XSLT transformations, and Notepad++ allows it.

Open your Notepad and paste this into it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StageAssessment[Year[text()='2014']]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Name as `remove-node-with-child.xsl` and save it to your disk as UTF-8 file.

Then, go to *Plugins* > *XML Tools*, choose *XSLT Transformation*, and in the *XSL Transformation settings* window select the XSL you have just saved. Click *Transform* button.

Regex patterns that will work for you but that I do not recommend are provided in the hidden "spoiler" below.

```js
A very resource consuming pattern based on the tempered greedy tokens:

(?s)<StageAssessment>(?:(?!</?StageAssessment>).)*<Year>2014</Year>(?:(?!</?Sta‌geAssessment>).)*</StageAssessment>
                      
And this one is much better: 

<StageAssessment>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?StageAssessment>|Year>)[^<]*)*<Year>2014</Year>[‌​^<]*(?:<(?!/?StageAssessment>)[^<]*)*</StageAssessment>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can do it using the find and replace with **Regular Expression** and **.matches newline** selected.

Alternatively, you could use another approach using XSLT and XML Tools for more cleaner solution. This solution could be very confusing when you face the more complex scenario.

***XML Sample***

```
<StageAssessment>
    <Locale>ENG</Locale>
    <Year>2014</Year>
    <Subject>SCI</Subject>
    <Method>TA</Method>
    <Component>AT1</Component>
    <ResultStatus>R</ResultStatus>
    <ResultQualifier>NL</ResultQualifier>
    <Result>3</Result>
    <ResultDate>2014-07-25</ResultDate>
</StageAssessment>
<StageAssessment>
    <Locale>ENG</Locale>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <Subject>SCI</Subject>
    <Method>TA</Method>
    <Component>AT1</Component>
    <ResultStatus>R</ResultStatus>
    <ResultQualifier>NL</ResultQualifier>
    <Result>3</Result>
</StageAssessment>
```

***Regex (Tested in Sublime)***:

```
(?s)<StageAssessment>(?:(?!<\/StageAssessment>).)*<Year>2015<\/Year>.*?<\/StageAssessment>
```

You could find the regex evaluator sample [here](http://rubular.com/r/iD3lmduCF7). Somehow i have to change the multiline operator to *(?s)* to get it working.

I hope it helps!!

[image]

Comment: The idea is to only remove `<StageAssessment>` nodes if the node has a `<Year>` child with `2014` text. The best approach is to use an XSLT template and process it with XML Tools.

Comment: I could not agree more to use XSLT template so that we could playing around with the query. Anyway, I have changed the regex to be more clear.

Comment: You mean you experimented with my regexps? Then provide an explanation of what the regex does.

Comment: Not yours actually, I have edited my previous expression that was not working perfectly earlier --> <StageAssessment>[\s\S]*?<\/StageAssessment>

Comment: And in the answer in the spoiler. If you explain the pattern in the answer, it will be OK for me. However, it is all up to you. As I say, a regex like this can easily hang the computer with a file with several hundred megabytes of text. XML files I have seen were up to 20GB :-O.